# Composer not updating Drupal Modules

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I am trying to update some Drupal modules using Composer.

When I run `composer outdated "drupal\*"` to see what updates are available, it shows a list of modules requiring an update.

[image]

But when I run `composer update <module-name> --with-dependencies` it gives me a memory allocation error.

[image]

If I run it with `sudo` (not recommended, I know. But trying everything.), it does nothing. No error reported. Nothing.

[image]

I have tried `composer clearcache` already but it didn't help any. What am I doing wrong? Why is this so?

Comment: Looks like you try to run `composer update`  on a cloud-based server with only little RAM. Don't do that, run these stuff on your development system where you are not constrained to such little memory

Comment: Is it a recent change to composer memory requirements? I have updated this so many, many times before but never ran into this issue before? Does swap files have anything to do with it?

Comment: Not running Composer on a server with only little memory, but on your local machine, put `composer.lock` under version control, and only run `composer install` during development has been recommended for years

Answer (score 0):

you can try `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 <module-name> --with-dependencies` this lets composer use as much memory as needed.

Comment: I don't think it's a memory issue. I tried with -1, 1024M memory as well as 2048M. No difference. It says Killed before returning to command prompt.

Comment: you may need to take a deep dive into whats running on your server. i was able to find another thread where someone had the same issue but im not sure if the solution will work for you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634109/why-mmap-cannot-allocate-memory]